No puedo ver las imágenes en el servidor con Python-Django
El servidor es  LiteSpeed Web Server el cual es un remplazo de Apache, según me dicen en soporte técnico
LAs imágenes se van guardando en settings.py:
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/servici1/public_html/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT ='/home/servici1/public_html/mundo/media'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
Las imágenes en template están en este directorio
img src="/media/foto/IMG-20191028-WA0003.jpg"
Este codigo de arriba lo tomé desde html que me debería mostrar
Se guardan correctamente en el directorio /foto/XXX en el servidor. Mi programa las guarda bien, ya observé que las imagenes están fisicamente con administrador de archivos, pero con mi código python-django, no me muestra nada.
Este es el código que despliega la imagen en mi computadora , ´pero no en el servidor:
img src="{{request.user.perfil.foto.url}}" >
Evidente la instruccion " img" va precedido de signo de menor que. No los puedo poner aqui porque se intenta poner una foto y ya no sale el código
Alguien puede ayudarme?  Llevo varios dias tratando y se meacaban las ideas.
